# Define custom login shell in schroot

Tags: shell, chroot

According to the schroot man page:

> schroot  allows  the user to run a command or a login shell in a chroot environment.  If no command is specified, a login shell will be started in the user's current working directory inside the chroot.

In my case schroot tries to run /bin/bash when no command is specified. Is there any way to have schroot use a different login shell by default ?

Comment: Can't you copy your user line in `/etc/passwd` and only  change the username and login shell (keeping the UID etc)?

Comment: Alternatively, you might want to change the /bin/sh symlink in the chroot

Answer (score 3):

Set the `shell=/bin/shell` in your `/etc/schroot/schroot.conf` file:

Referencing the *schroot.conf man page*:

> **shell=shell**
>   When running a login shell a number of potential shells will be considered, in this order: the command in the SHELL environment variable (if  --preserve-environment  is  used,  or  pre‐serve-environment  is enabled), the user's shell in the ‘passwd’ database, /bin/bash and finally /bin/sh.  This setting overrides this list, and will use the shell specified.  It may be overridden using the --shell option.

Comment: Uhm, my schroot does not seem to support this option (and it is not listed in my schroot.conf manpage...)

Comment: Which OS are you running @Grodriguez?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 (yes I know this is old)